# Problem using "Any" method inside "Where" method in Linq MongodbDriver

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new in using linq and having some problem . I've got a big collection of type A and a small collection of type B.
I want the list of items in A which their "id" does exist in B.
So here is what I did think could work:

```
List<string> list = collection_A
                .Where(c => collection_B.Any(x => x.MessageId == c.Id))
                .Select(c=>c.Id)
                .ToList();
```

I'm using mongoDB linq provider in .Net and the error is : System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter. The relation is 1-1

Actually I don't know if I should use "Join" in this case or something else.

Comment: What you have done is appropriate for your described use-case, no need to use `Join`. Could you please post more information on the exception you are getting? Which method throws it and what is the actual argument that causes the issue?

Comment: If `Type A` and `Type B` relation is 1-N and you want only those `A` that have `B` related items you could just `collection_A.Where(c=> C.collection_B.Any())`

Comment: I'm using mongoDB linq provider in .Net and the error is : System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter. The relation is 1-1

Comment: Please use the edit link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55810492/edit to improve your question adding relevant data.

Comment: @Zdeněk Jelínek You are right. I checked it with in-memory collections and it works fine. the problem happens because **mongodb** linq driver does not support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you try this:

```
var messageIds = new HashSet<string>(collection_B.Select(x => x.MessageId).Distinct());

List<string> list =
    collection_A
        .Where(c => messageIds.Contains(c.Id))
        .Select(c => c.Id)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your problem correctly, the following code will point you in the right direction.
i've used MongoDAL for data access which is just an abstraction around the c# driver.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDAL;

namespace Example
{
    class Person : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class BanRecord : Entity
    {
        public One<Person> Person { get; set; }
        public string ReasonForBan { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("testdatabase");

            var person1 = new Person { Name = "Person One" };
            var person2 = new Person { Name = "Person Two" };
            var person3 = new Person { Name = "Person Three" };

            person1.Save();
            person2.Save();
            person3.Save();

            var ban1 = new BanRecord
            {
                Person = person1.ToReference(),
                ReasonForBan = "Cause we can!"
            };
            ban1.Save();

            var ban2 = new BanRecord
            {
                Person = person2.ToReference(),
                ReasonForBan = "Cause we can!"
            };
            ban2.Save();

            var bannedPeople = (from b in DB.Collection<BanRecord>()
                                join p in DB.Collection<Person>() on b.Person.ID equals p.ID into banned
                                from p in banned
                                select p).ToArray();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```